# Lighthouse: Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy

Tags: caching, static, assets, lighthouse

I have optimized a website using the Chrome Lighthouse extension. I'm using in the .htaccess the expires headers for the cache control. Images and videos are set to:

ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

What I did not find out, is why Lighthouse reports:

Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy for more than 50 resources including the images that are listed with Cache TTL 30d

Has anybody of you an idea how I can improve these cache settings?

Comment: You can check if your settings are in action as expected - pick a gif / jpg URL and try curl -I <YourStaticFileURLHere> In the response, look for Cache-Control header. If you don't see one - your cache control settings are not working. Try this in that case : https://www.tezify.com/how-to/serve-static-assets-with-an-efficient-cache-policy/

Comment: Thank you Punit, I double checked and found out that the cache headers are set correctly to 90d = 90 days. I changed that to 365d and retested with Lighthouse -> no error message anymore.